# Уточнение или просто однородные члены?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли указанная в скобках запятая?

*Вот почему нам сегодня даются такие события, которые становятся не для всех, но уже для многих(,) средой для своего очищения и внутренних преобразований.*

Comment: Ответ обновлен. Просто меня сбило правило Розенталя, когда уточнение отделяется только с одной стороны. Ситуация другая, но интонация такая же.

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, сочетание «не для всех, но уже для многих» является вставной конструкцией: предложение прерывается для внесения некой короткой корректирующей информации, а потом продолжается. Я бы препинался так:
Вот почему нам сегодня даются такие события, которые становятся(не для всех, но уже для многих) средой для своего очищения и внутренних преобразований.

Comment: Да, ещё один вариант для правки, но не вводным сочетанием (при котором нельзя задать вопрос), а вставной конструкцией

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, наиболее удачным можно назвать такое оформление, как у Jim Korbett:
Вот почему нам сегодня даются такие события, которые становятся (не для всех, но уже для многих) средой для очищения и внутренних преобразований.

1. Почему? По семантике конструкция «не для всех, но уже для многих» явно ВСТАВОЧНАЯ, так как  прерывается естественное глагольное управление: становятся (чем?) средой.  Обособить это сочетание запятыми (как уточнение)  сложно – в этом случае  грамматика предложения может быть не понята читателями. Перестановкой здесь ничего изменить нельзя.

Интерес же вызывает другой аспект дискуссии, а именно обсуждение самой конструкции (не для всех, но уже для многих), в которой вместо привычного союза А использован союз НО.

2. В грамматике такое противопоставление НЕ...А называется замещением:
   [http://rusgram.ru/Сочинительные_союзы#322](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%8B#322)   Семантически заместительные союзы НЕ… А, НЕ… НО близки конструкциям с предлогом ВМЕСТО, указывающим на «замещение», «зачеркивание» одной ситуации другой.
   В русистике союз НЕ... А и синонимичный ему  у с т а р е в ш и й  союз НЕ... НО обычно рассматриваются не как отдельные единицы, а как КОМБИНАЦИЯ соответствующих союзов с отрицанием.
3. Но стоит ли считать вариант с союзом НО устаревшим?  Возможен такой подход, когда  ОТДЕЛЬНО учитывается значение союзов  А и НО.  Можно считать, что «устаревший»  вариант с союзом НО – это не простое «зачеркивание», а особо подчеркнутое, у с и л е н н о е, так как основным противительным союзом является союз НО (отсюда следует кажущаяся возвышенность и героичность подобных конструкций). Что касается союза А, то его главное значение – сопоставительное, а не противительное.
   Уже приведенный здесь пример:  «Я слышу речь не мальчика, но мужа» (А. С. Пушкин «Борис Годунов»).

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (ответ на комментарий oleedd)

1. Можно написать так: «Вот почему нам сегодня даются такие события, которые СТАНОВЯТСЯ не для всех, но уже для многих СРЕДОЙ для своего очищения и внутренних преобразований».

Без проблем!  По пунктуации запись верная,  а вот  по стилю, грамматике и семантике требуется редактирование. Почему?  Конструкция явно ВСТАВОЧНАЯ, так как разрывается естественная глагольная связь –  «становятся средой». Еще не высказана основная мысль, а уже дается уточнение, причем в такой позиции, где требуется обособление.  Это можно назвать грамматической и семантической неточностью.

Ничего не исправляя, можно поставить скобки. Это не лучший вариант (с этим соглашусь), но иначе надо ВСЕ ПЕРЕСТРАИВАТЬ, да и контекст надо при этом видеть. В противном случае любое другое редактирование ничего не изменит, тогда зачем этим вообще заниматься?

2. Об «устаревшей» конструкции НЕ…НО

Действительно, в статье о сочинительных союзах (Русская корпусная грамматика) так написано. Я не считаю вариант  НЕ…НО устаревшим, но полагаю его подчеркнутым и усиленным. Кстати, сама часто пользуюсь НЕ…НО (даже в этом предложении).  Союз НО здесь очень хорош, неужели это не чувствуется!  А в полемике  он просто незаменим, придает высказыванию категоричность и эмоциональность.

Очень выразительный союз, с чего бы это ему устареть?  Наш язык очень экономный, вряд ли он будет просто так  «разбрасываться» союзами. Кстати, где еще можно увидеть информацию о том, что он устаревший. Могу предположить, что форма НЕ…НО активно применяется, но примеры надо искать.

Comment: "но не Диккенса" — автономное примечание, всё в порядке. А устаревший вариант таков: *Он любит не английскую литературу, но русскую.* Вопрос лишь о запятой и о уточнении/однородности, поэтому никакие другие варианты оформления не рассматривал. А скобки — отличный вариант уйти от проблемы)

Comment: Лучше писать "ответ обновлен" (в комментарии) или что-то типа того (потом можно удалить). Оповещения об обновлениях не приходят, случайно заметил.

Comment: "Союз НО здесь очень хорош, неужели это не чувствуется!" — так люди не говорят, режет слух. "Я не считаю вариант НЕ…НО устаревшим" — ха, а это предложение самостоятельное, а дальше идёт самостоятельное примечание (его можно изъять) — поэтому сразу ничего и не заметил, в отличие от: *Сегодня не Петя, но Маша придёт.* У вас такая структура: *Такого не происходит, но происходит другое.*

Comment: Ага, теперь будем обсуждать пример из корпусной грамматики. А давайте я его вычеркну: нет примера - нет обсуждения примера.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Интересно.

Comment: Роман, скажите, пожалуйста, что-нибудь конкретное. У вас очень интересный вопрос, хотелось бы знать ваше мнение об ответах.

Comment: oleedd, я исправила ответ, упростив его. Много лишних подробностей, которые перетягивают на себя внимание.

Comment: Sharon, напишу как-нибудь, может, через несколько дней - сейчас не могу долго здесь находиться, ответ прочитал бегло. Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо, обязательно напишите.

Comment: Дело в том, что это один из самых сложных и проблемных вопросов в принципе (грань между однородностью и уточнением), темы подобного уровня (а их мало), которые не расписаны в правилах, есть смысл обсуждать.

Comment: Уточнение или однородные отношения нужно определять для каждого конкретного случая. и в каждом случае свои проблемы и свои решения.  Здесь приходится практически ОДНОЗНАЧНО  выбирать уточнение, потому что нарушена связь в глагольном сочетании (грамматический фактор) и нарушена логика изложения (дополнительная информация прерывает основную, это семантический фактор).

Answer (score 1):

Уточнение (запятая нужна), потому что при однородных должен быть союз "а" вместо "но" в данном случае, что связано с наличием частицы "не".

Примеры Розенталя:
*Они получили небольшую, **но удобную** квартиру.

**Не** род, **а ум** поставлю в воеводы.

Каждый вечер солнце садилось в море, **а не в тучи** и было при этом клюквенного цвета.*

"*Но уже для многих*" по смыслу похоже на примечание, вставку.
"*Но уже для многих*" важнее по смыслу, чем "*не для всех*", и, как следствие, при изъятии первого (уточнения) предложение становится не особо удачным, поэтому предпочтительна такая структура в плане стилистики:
*Вот почему нам сегодня даются такие события, которые становятся уже для многих, но не для всех, средой для своего очищения и внутренних преобразований.*

Update:
Использование "не ..., но" (с одной запятой) вместо "не ..., а" устарело:
*Сегодня не Петя, но Маша придёт.

Мороженое куплено не для тебя, но для него.

Он пришёл не с собакой, но с кошкой к нам в гости.*
Поэтому запятая нужна. Но оно сохранилось в двойных союзах (пример в конце).
В каких-то случаях оно может лучше звучать, в каких-то — хуже.
Фрагмент с "но" является дополнительной информацией, вставкой, обособленным примечанием, но не уточнением, потому что нельзя уточнить то, чего нет (так как используется частица "не").
Если поменять местами, как предложено выше, то будет "запах" плеоназма, так как "для многих" подразумевает "что не для всех". По смыслу там желательно обойтись без запятой (чтобы не обособлять более значимую информацию) — ещё один вариант редактирования:
*Вот почему нам сегодня даются такие события, которые становятся **хоть и не** для всех, **но** уже для многих средой для своего очищения и внутренних преобразований.*

Update 2:
Розенталь (это по части моего первого абзаца):
Различается противопоставление, выраженное союзом "а", и противопоставление, выраженное союзом "но". При использовании союза "а" один из двух противоположных друг другу признаков отрицается, а другой — утверждается: *река **не** глубокая, **а** мелкая* — **раздельное** написание отрицательной частицы.
При использовании союза "но" соединяемые понятия **не противопоставляются** друг другу, так как они вполне совместимы, т. е. предмету одновременно приписываются **два признака без отрицания одного из них**: *река **неглубокая**, **но** холодная* — **слитное** написание отрицательной частицы.
http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Только пример с **удобной** квартирой не вписывается в содержание первого предложения ответа.

Comment: Ну так "но" тоже может быть, там "небольшая" вместе: *такая, но вот такая*, а не: *не такая, но вот такая*. Так что оно вписывается. Здесь не всё так просто. Ещё планирую поразбираться, но в любом случае оно лучше смотрится как обособленное примечание.

Comment: Возможно даже, что допустимы два варианта. Это пытаюсь выяснить. Если так, то как вам выбрать? По наличию логического ударения на "многих" и паузы.

Comment: *потому что при однородных должен быть союз "а" вместо "но" в данном случае, что связано с наличием частицы "не".* - я совершенно не понял смысла этого условия/правила/рекомендации. Вот пример из Нацкорпуса (неавторитетный, но искать что-то ещё сейчас не могу ): *Как пронзен был, как безжалостно убит, как не от врага, но от своего брата смерть воспринял?* Как здесь насчет запятой по вашему "правилу"?

Comment: Тут похожая ситуация. Мне кажется, что здесь вместо "а" подставили "но", и воспринимается оно в смысле "а". Здесь нужны не авторитетные примеры, а с грамматикой разобраться.

Comment: @oleedd на что, простите, похожая? *вместо "а" подставили "но", и воспринимается оно в смысле "а"* - так и я о том. Что ни поставь - смысл тот же. **"Я слышу речь не мальчика, но мужа"** (П) - как ни меняй "но" на "а", смысл не изменится. Или для вас он поменяется? Тогда объясните разницу.

Comment: Нет, для меня просто не звучит (с "но"), сейчас так не говорят, когда-то, по всей видимости, активно говорили.

Comment: Что-то где-то читал, может даже у Розенталя, что "но" придаёт тексту возвышенность, героичность, что ли. Мало шансов найти.

Comment: В ответ добавлено правило Розенталя (которое случайно нашёл благодаря вам), что подтверждает моё первое предложение ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая - на усмотрение автора. Я бы поставил её - в силу своего понимания смыслового акцента фразы. Здесь "но уже для многих" несет (по моему разумению) ярко выраженный уточняющий характер, без этого уточнения фраза наполняется совершенно иным смысл.

Правил насчет того, что обособление как-то связано с конструкцией "не..., но..." я не знаю. "Не..., но..." и "но..., а..." в подобном контексте грамматически взаимозаменяемы, хотя могут нести несколько разный смысл.

Comment: Не могу, к сожалению, сейчас писать подробно, если потребуется, разовью мысль позже.

Comment: *Здесь "но уже для многих" несет (по моему разумению) ярко выраженный уточняющий характер* — вот так и мне показалось. Было бы "а" вместо "но" — было бы по-другому.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @oleedd  *Было бы "а" вместо "но" — было бы по-другому.* - С чего бы? По-другому бы бвло, если это эта часть была вовсе опущена.  А те трудноразличимые оттенки смысла (если они вообще есть в данном контексте) никак не сказываются на пунктуации.